# Как запросить админ права при запуске ? И проверить наличие их

Tags: java, windows, windows-10

Нужно именно в программе, при её запуске, запросить админ права и сделать проверку на них. Сделать нужно в самом классе(мейне), но не отдельным файлом. Если есть способы без запроса повысить свои права, то как можно сделать? Может можно как-то через командную строку винды это сделать?(запрос на админ права)